# Merging two index into one index in QByteArray in QT

Tags: arrays, qt

I have a QByteArray which contains data like below:

```
[0] --> A
[1] --> B
[2] --> C
[3] --> D
```

I want to do it like below:

```
[0] --> AB
[1] --> CD
```

Is it possible. How can I do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. You can't directly just use the QByteArray to achieve what you want as each index only stores one byte.

One solution is to let each index in a vector correspond to a QByteArray (including the merge):

```
QByteArray byteArray("ABCDEFG");
QVector<QByteArray> vectorByteArray;
for (auto i = 0; i < byteArray.size(); i += 2) {
  vectorByteArray << QByteArray(byteArray.constData() + i, (i + 1 == byteArray.size()) ? 1 : 2);
}

for (auto & element : vectorByteArray) {
  qDebug() << element.constData();
}
```